# Is it good to use hidden fields to pass form field labels to php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to get a definitive way to build email messages with data inputs from web forms without having to map every field name to its related label. I try to better explain here:

```
<label for="project">Project name</label>
<input name="project" id="project" type="text"  value="" />
```

When I receive `$_POST` data, I'll have to manually do something like:

```
$msg .= 'Project name:' . $_POST['project']
```

So if I've got 30 fields, I'll have to hand-write all the 30 labels to build the final mail message. So I thought that maybe, I could exploit hidden fields to pass labels, like this:

```
<label for="project">Project name</label>
<input name="project[]" id="project" type="text"  value="" />
<input name="project[label]" type="hidden" value="Project name">
```

So I can do something like this:

```
$msg .= $_POST['project'][0] . ': ' . $_POST['project_name']['label']
```

It just works. But the question is: is it good practice?

Comment: Put simply. No its not a good idea

Comment: Ok thank you, why?

Comment: It's not good idea **if** you don't do some backend checks first. Anything that the user sends can be manipulated.

Comment: They maybe hidden but anyone with even just a little knowledge can change those on the browser and make a nonsense of your output

Comment: As someone could post data without using your form they can send different values than your desired values and that would alter your created email

Comment: This question seems off topic on this site, maybe try on Code Review instead.

Comment: Why would you want to send field names in the request? Map field names to labels _server-side_.

Comment: Assuming you check your user input why not use $msg .= $_POST['project'][0] . ': ' . $_POST['project_name'][label[0]]and then you can loop through your data

Comment: I'd screw this form just to try. Sanitize your inputs, but don't give access to the message body !

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not good practice.

If you want to automate it, build an array of `key => label` in your PHP and loop over it:

```
$labels = [
    'project' => 'Project Name',
    'creator' => 'Creator',
    'programming_language' => 'Programming Language'
];

$msg = '';
foreach ($labels as $key => $label) {
    $msg .= $label . ': ' . $_POST[$key];
}
```

Comment: Mmm ok, I already do it but it's a quite tedious process... I hoped I found a smarter way... but it's right, it's not a good practice. Thank you.

Comment: How is it tedious? You only have to edit one array to do everything. You can even use this array to build your form automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Security:**
As said, it is **not a good practice** as shown in your question, you would need to check your labels, because *anyone can modify your fields* and could destroy the message body of your mail.

**Time consuming:**
You probably want to do this to gain time, but doing this in a secure way need more data validation and you will end writing more code (and write your labels content multiple times).